# Benefits of BPM over ESB

Tags: esb

I'm experienced in developing Integration solutions using various ESB tools like Mule ESB, Dell Boomi, Oracle OSB. Recently, I figured out BPM tools are not only useful for implementing Business Logic but also capable of integrating with various systems and applications like DB, LDAP etc.
What makes ESB special compared to BPM?

Comment: Apologies for the Subject line it should be "Benefits of ESB compared with BPM".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

great question.

The role of the two are different.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_process_management

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_service_bus

BPM is intended to guide a series of business transactions through to resolution.

ESB is intended to provide loosely coupled services to the enterprise.

ANY tool, whether ESB, BPM, or APPLICATION CONTAINER, can read and write from the database, connect to web services, access message queues.

The focus of BPM is not the same as the focus of an ESB.

An ESB replaces directly coupled (tightly coupled) connections between applications with indirectly coupled (loosely coupled) connections. This abstraction enables one application to be upgraded or changed without requiring the connected application to do the same. The beauty of the ESB lies in its platform-agnostic nature and the ability to integrate with anything at any condition.

BPM provides operational intelligence (business logic) to business processes. This is in stark contrast to ESB which specifically excludes business logic from ESB processing. ESB provides three key values to the equation : service aggregation, context-based routing, and transformation. While a BPM engine can also provide these, it typically does not. A BPM engine would typically call an ESB to leverage the ESB's strength when transforming payloads. They usually work together, in concert.

The ESB enables the enterprise to build granular services and re-combine services over time to form new applications that were never contemplated when those granular services were first implemented. The ESB can enrich business transactions with combinations of data from different services. Think of BPM as the conductor of an orchestra and the ESB as combining the value of each individual instrument in the orchestra to form new and different value propositions.

Lance